# Is n1>n2>n3 possible with a Neural Network?

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network

I am trying to better understand Neural Networks, so I first built a Perceptron and then a simple multilayer Network.
My NN can easily learn the greater than (>) operator. Or check if two numbers added are equal to a third (which I think isn't possible with a Perceptron):

```
n1 + n2 == n3 # with n being the inputs, eg.:
n1, n2, n3 = 0.4, 0.3, 0.7
# output -> 1 for true
```

But I just can't get it to learn n1>n2>n3. Eg.:

```
n1, n2, n3 = 12, 7, 2 # 12>7>2 -> output=1
n1, n2, n3 = 12, 34, 2 # 12>34>2 -> output=0
```

My Question is, is this problem possible with a simple multilayer Neural Network and there is a problem with my NN or is it just impossible?

**EDIT:**
With "simple multilayer Neural Network" I mean a Neural Network that has 2 or more hidden Layers. In my case it's 2, maybe 3 Layers.

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible or not. But in Modeling, you tend to split issue into smaller tasks. For each task you create a model and then you combine these metamodels into big one. Your usecase can be a nice example. Instead of trying to create one complex model you can use 3 times simple one. 
For examle: You want to identify cars / bikes / people on the image. 1. task: identify area with objects & 2. task classification of these areas, where classes are: car / bike / people.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you mean by "simple multilayer Neural Network"? It's impossible to tell what it can or cannot do otherwise.

Comment: Look up "universal approximation theorem".

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise, but knowing `>` isn't enough to evaluate a chained comparison. You also need to know what `and` means.